# How to make Multiply function inside a Class Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, properties

What am I missing here in the code or in function area? any pieces of advice? if anybody knows a very good place to study from it object-oriented programming please tell me and thanks.

```
class Square():
def __init__(self,height=0,width=0):
    self._height = height
    self._width = width

@property
def height(self):
    return self._height

@property
def width(self):
    return self._width

def area(self):
    return height * width

@height.setter
def set_height(self,new_height):
    self._height = new_height

@width.setter
def set_width(self,new_width):
    self._width = new_width
```

Comment: Unrelated to your main issue: If you're not doing any validation or calculations in your `property` methods, you should probably do away with them and just access `height` and `width` variables directly. On the other hand, `area` might be a good candidate to be a `property`, if you don't want to need to explicitly call it.

Comment: @blckknght the answer that i get is this <bound method Square.area of <__main__.Square object at 0x0000023DB821A1D0>>

Comment: You either need to make it a property, or call it. You seem to be doing neither.

Comment: If an answer is correct (like the given one) you should tick the Correct check mark for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `self.height` and `self.width` in your area function.

Also the name of your setters should match your getters. Something like this.

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self, height=0, width=0):
        self._height = height
        self._width = width

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.width

    @height.setter
    def height(self, new_height):
        self._height = new_height

    @width.setter
    def width(self, new_width):
        self._width = new_width
```

Then you must instantiate the class, and use the returned object to access it's properties and methods, like so.

```
s = Square(2, 4)
s.area()
s.height = 6
```

Comment: thank you @joarobot but I tried that and it doesn't give e any answer it gives this( <bound method Square.area of <__main__.Square object at 0x0000023DB821A1D0>>)

Comment: @Encode.to.code I have updated the answer with an example of how to instantiate a class. There are many different ways to learn a new language, depending on which learning method works best for you. Doing exercises like this is one way, another that I found particularly useful was reading through the O'Reilly Introduction to Python book. But the internet is full of useful resources if you don't want to invest in a book.

Comment: Would you like to post the error you are getting @Encode.to.code

Comment: its not an error this is the output <function __main__.Square.area> @joerobot